# Submit apps in appstore with xcode7

Tags: xcode7

Can you submit apps in the appstore with xcode 7? Or is this not possible because it's stil in beta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple will probably not be accepting apps created for iOS 9 or OS X 10.11 before we get closer to the actual release of the two operating systems (later in the fall).

At least that was the case in 2014 where I received a mail in september asking developers to start submitting their apps written in Swift (version 1 at that point) and targeted iOS 8. It's likely that it'll be the case this time too.